# Automatically retrieve notion token_v2

Tags: reactjs, notion

I'm using [react-notion-x](https://github.com/NotionX/react-notion-x). And I'm trying to render our private pages. As stated [here](https://github.com/NotionX/react-notion-x#private-pages), we added these:

```
const notion = new NotionAPI({
  activeUser: process.env.ACTIVE_USER,
  authToken: process.env.TOKEN_V2
})
```

And the ACTIVE_USER and TOKEN_V2 are retrieved using the dev tools:

```
Development Tools > Application > Cookie > and Copy the token_v2 and notion_user_id
```

The problem is that occasionally the **token_v2** and/or the **notion_user_id** changes. When it happens, our app won't be able to load those pages by surprise. Which in turn would force us to manually copy it again and reboot the server for the environment changes to take effect.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to automate in getting the token data in Dev Tools?